# sqlite SELECT CASE error 'only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression'

Tags: sqlite

Que tal tengo una querie en sqlite con la siguiente sintaxis:

```
select 
case when (SELECT campo1, campo2 from TABLA_A ) IS NULL THEN
(select 0 as campo1 , 0 as campo2 ) ELSE
(SELECT campo1, campo2 from TABLA_A ) END
```

El primer select es nulo. Entonces, deberia devolver los campos con 0.
Al parecer la sintaxis es correcta pero me arroja el error '`only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression`'

¿Cual sería el problema?

Answer (score 3):

El error te está diciendo, en otras palabras, que el resultado dentro del `CASE` devuelve más de una fila, y que lo que estás haciendo (`SELECT` dentro de un `CASE`) no está permitido por ese motivo.

En tu caso particular, echale un vistazo a [`COALESCE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce), el cual acepta dos o más argumentos y devuelve una copia del primer argumento no nulo (o `NULL` si todos los argumentos son nulos).

La consulta entonces quedaría:

```
SELECT COALESCE(campo1, 0), COALESCE(campo2, 0) 
FROM tabla_a
```